# Equation for a DiD/Event Study Combining Several Simple DiD

Tags: econometrics, difference-in-difference, misspecification

I am trying to do a Difference in Differences/Dynamic Event Study but my data doens't easily lend itself to a classic staggered treatment DiD nor a simple 2X2 DiD. My dataset has 1-min readings from 100 immobile sensors in a neighborhood. The treatment is a gas being released (this only lasts for 30 mins-1 hour). The sensors in the treatment group are those in the specific direction from where the gas was released while all the other sensors are in the control group. The sensors have parallel trends before the gas release so each gas release would be a simple 2x2 DiD.

However, the gas has been released on several occasions (almost once a day) over a 5-month period. Instead of running one DiD on the first time it was released, I want to combine all the data. My dataset would not be a normal staggered DiD because a sensor doesn't switch from not being treated to being treated for the rest of the dataset. It's a compilation of the readings from all the sensors for each day 2 hours before and after the gas is released which means on one day, it could be assigned treatment depending on its location/direction to the gas source that day and on another day it wouldn't. Like I mentioned, technically, each gas release event could be its own simple 2x2 DiD with a control and treatment group made from the readings from all the sensors 2 hours before and after the event, but I would like to use all the gas release events together to take advantage of more data (I hope it's clear how this isn't a multiple staggered DiD).

My initial idea was just centering the data around the respective gas release times and then running a simple 2x2 DiD as if the gas releases all happened at once and then include fixed effects (time and sensor) as controls to the equation, but this might be naive. However, doing a multiple staggered DiD also seems off.

A second thing I want to consider is the fact that the sensors' distance to the gas could also affect their readings and I'd like to have multiple treatment interaction terms that are dummies based on the distance but haven't been able to pull this off with the tutorials for multiple staggered DiD packages in R or python though I could create these manually if doing a simple DiD. There is also the question of clustering based on the gas event or on the sensor level. This is a lot, but thanks for your help!

Comment: Question: “The sensors in the treatment group are those *in the specific direction* from where the gas was released…” So it’s not just *where* the gas comes from but also the direction it’s going. Is this correct? Second, is a treated area consisted “not treated” 2-hours after the release of the gas on a specific day?